# Why does this map is well-defined?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-verification, algebraic-curves

I didn't understand this proof from Fulton's Algebraic curves book:

[image]
[image]

Why $ord_P(f)\ge -r-1$ in order to this map be well-defined?

Thanks

Comment: You can only evaluate a rational function (to get a value in $k$) at a point if $f$ is actually regular there. Happily, $\operatorname{ord}_P(t^{p+1}f) \geq 0$ since $t$ has order $1$. Maybe I don't understand the exact point of confusion.

Comment: @Hoot thank you very much for the explanation!